# pass argument to camera activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera-intent

I referred several posts to pass arguments to camera activity but of no use. Below is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photocapture);
        ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.clickme);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                 cameraIntent.putExtra("s", 10);
                 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST); 
            }
        });
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            String s = b.getString("s");//(String)data.getExtras().get("s");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            ib.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }  
    }
```

But i am not able to pass them successfully. People who have been able to do it successfully, please help!

Answer (score 1):

You set param to camera intent and you ask param from another actvity. This not right. If you want send spesific setting param to camera activity you read this documentation:

[Use Android Camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

If you need pass not settings params to camera activity, then you create global variable in current activity and use it is in onActivityResult method.

Comment: Please don't provide code-only answers. Give a description of what you have changed and why it works. Also, the question was about sending params to the camera activity, not returning them

Comment: if you pass params to A intent, you make get it is params from only A intent.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the replies, i added my param with requestCode, and at the receiver received and proceeded with it. Thanks for the reply!